# Laravel How to find Mutual Friends from model?

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-8, mutual-friendship

I am using laravel 8.
I want to find the mutual friends of entries and profiles.

Please ask me if it is not clear...

My friends table;

```
user_friends;
id | user_id | user_friend_id
1  | 10      | 20
2  | 20      | 10
```

In My User Model;

```
    public function friends(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_friends', 'user_id', 'user_friend_id');
    }

    public function friendsOf(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_friends', 'user_friend_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

How can I find mutual friends of the profile with respect to authenticated user?

Example;

```
@foreach($user as $entry)
{{ count( $entry->mutual(Auth::id()) ) }}
  @foreach($entry->mutual(Auth::id()) as $item)
   {{ $item->name }}
   ...
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make this work by using helpers. I create helpers.php on App folder and create a function.

```
function mutualFriends($id){
 $profile = User::where('id', $id)->first();
 $profileFriends = $profile->friends;
 $profileFriendsIds = [];
   foreach ($profileFriends as $entry){
     $profileFriendsIds[] = $entry->id;
    }
 $loggedUserFriends = Auth::user()->friends->whereIn('id', $profileFriendsIds);

 return $loggedUserFriends;
}
```

and now I am calling the function from view like;

```
{{count(mutualFriends(Auth::id()))}}
```

or

```
@foreach(mutualFriends($profile->id) as $entry)
...
@endforeach
```